# Best sorting and formatting algorithm for flat data to directed graph tree

Tags: java, algorithm, parsing, graph, tree-traversal

Given flat data like this:

```
01001, Butter, salted
01002, Butter, whipped, with salt
01145, Butter, without salt
04601, Butter, light, stick, with salt
04602, Butter, light, stick, without salt
```

What's the best approach to convert into this:

```
Butter (01001, 01002, 01145, 04601, 04602) -> salted (01001)
                     -> whipped (01002) -> with salt (01002)
                     -> without salt (01145) 
                     -> light (04601, 04602) -> stick  (04601, 04602) -> with salt (04601)
                                                                      -> without salt (04602)
```

I was thinking of recursive sorting first, but I realized there may be a lot of string comparisons to be efficient.

Comment: personally, I think you ought to explain the i/o format a bit more. It's confusing to me.

Comment: Is there a systematic mapping between the product code and an attribute such as with salt?

Comment: i managed to answer my own question, though only in part. thanks everyone!

Comment: Duplicate: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/27951/algorithm-for-creating-a-directed-graph-using-flat-data-input